# MFC MDI : how i can handle when the program switch from a child window to another?

Tags: mfc, mdi

I have a MDI application and i need to do an action when the user (or the program) change from a child window to another.

I tried both with WM_ACTIVATE both on the View and the child frame who own it but with no avail.

Those child are created from CMultiDocTemplate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WM_MDIACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644911%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.